# a mechanism for auto unsubscribing from observables

Tags: typescript, inheritance, rxjs

In order to try and DRY my code when it comes to making sure that I unsubscribe from observable subscriptions I have created this class:

```
// autounsubscribe.ts 

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export abstract class AutoUnsubscribe {
    protected unsubscriber$ = new Subject<void>();

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.unsubscriber$.next();
        this.unsubscriber$.complete();
        console.log('unsubscribed');
    }

    protected subscribe(observable, fn) {
        return observable.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscriber$)).subscribe(fn);
    }
}
```

this can now be extended by other classes like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AutoUnsubscribe } from './autounsubscribe';

@Component({
    selector: 'nio-init',
    templateUrl: './init.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./init.component.scss']
})
export class InitComponent extends AutoUnsubscribe {
    private obs$: Observable<boolean> = new Observable();

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.subscribe(this.obs$, data => {
            console.log('new event', data);
        });
    }
}
```

This works : the subscription receives data when the observable changes, and when this component is destroyed, the console logs "unsubscribed"

However, as I am a relative noob typescript coder, I was wondering if

A) this is the most appropriate way, as I am starting to fall out of love with "extends/inherits" as it tends to hide things . Like "where did this.subscribe come from ? checks... oh yeah, must be in the class I'm extending from" etc

B) I have an itch to provide the same functionality via decorators but not entirely sure it's possible

C) how other people manage this process . I've seen several options, but most of them involve lots of DRY issues

I would appreciate your thoughts, comments and suggestions ;)

Comment: Just use the async pipe

Comment: When you have a super with ngOnDestroy you have to remember to call super.ngOnDestroy() if your component implements OnDestroy, You are guaranteed to forget to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is clever, but I think you'd be better off trying to leverage binding observables to your template with the `async` pipe.

```js
export class InitComponent {
    user$: Observable<UserModel>;

    constructor(userService: UserService) {
        this.user$ = userService.fetchUserData();
    }
}
```

Then you can easily work with your observable property in the template like so:

```html
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
  <h3>{{ user.name }}</h3>
  <p>{{ user.bio }}</p>
</div>
```

With the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), you don't have to worry about unsubscribing.

If you want more customized, derived properties, you can still leverage the `async` pipe.

```js
export class InitComponent {
    user$: Observable<UserModel>;

    get isUserQualified$(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.user$.pipe(map(u => u.age > 21 && u.weight >= 100));
    }

    constructor(userService: UserService) {
        this.user$ = userService.fetchUserData();
    }
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
  <h3>{{ user.name }}</h3>
  <p>{{ user.bio }}</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isUserQualified$ | async">
  <p>Special content for qualified users!</p>
</div>
```

You can use the many rxjs operators to map, filter, arrange, or whatever you need to do to the observable state.

Answer (score 0):

There is a libary called [subsink](https://github.com/wardbell/subsink) created by **Warbell** to unsubscribe multiple subscription in a component gracefully. It won't auto subscribe your subscriptions , but you can add multiple observables in to array unsubscribe together

You can see a small introduction about this plugin by [John Papa in a ng-conf 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZFgcTOcnUg)